# Invoke Webrequest, website that needs Microsoft login | Powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, credentials, webrequest

I want to make a `Invoke-WebRequest` to a webiste that needs microsoft authentification to log in. I have those microsoft credentials under a .cred file on my computer.

I tried this (but with no sucess) :

```
Import-CliXml -Path $pathtocredfile
Invoke-WebRequest "myurl" -Credential $cred
```

And that is how I obtained the .cred file :

```
$Credential = Get-Credential   #then I manually enter username and password
$Credential | Export-CliXml -Path $pathtocredfile
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does this work? `Invoke-WebRequest "myurl" -Credential (Get-Credential)`

Comment: Thanks @LievenKeersmaekers for your answer ! . No it's not working. I mean it doesn't pass the microsoft sign in

Comment: then your problem is not `Import-CliXml` but without any other information about the site and how it does authentication, there is little we can say about that.

Comment: The website is an Azure App Service which is using token to authenticate

Comment: I have next to nothing experience with the required flow but perhaps [this](https://blog.simonw.se/getting-an-access-token-for-azuread-using-powershell-and-device-login-flow/) might be of help to you. Getting a token requires some back and forth requests.

Comment: Thanks ! will look at it